# How read original file at Akamai HD?

Tags: video-streaming, akamai

I need to convert Flash player for videos located at Akamai HD servers to HTML 5 version. But I didn't work with Akamai in past so i total newbie in Akamai with limited time to develop.
Videos are already in MP4 format (MP4 container, H264 video). But its accesses as FLV container (it automatically transcoded at Akamai). Urls looks like http://something.akamaihd.net/file_part_4,3.,2.,mp4.csmil/.....&primaryToken=token .
What are first steps for me to access original files (i think there are some REST API)?
What additional access requirements I needed except tokens (in difference with access to FLV container)?
Thanks, for your patience with my newbie questions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the original files you need to create another configuration (for instance a Progessive Media Download configuration) which will use the same origin as the AkamaiHD configuration.
If you have token requirements, you will have to implement the token logic in the new configuration too. Please note: tokens are not a requirement for an HD configuration or any other type of configuration -- they are a feature you can turn on if needed.